# Catching custom error not working in Bluebird

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to throw and then catch a custom error in a Bluebird promise chain, but I can't get it to catch the custom error. For example:

```
function login(req, res, next) {
  function LoginError() {}

  return User.where('id', req.body.userId).fetch()
    .then(function (location) {
      if (req.body.password !== location.get('password')) {
        throw new LoginError();
      }

      // returns a promise
      return Subscription.where('userId', location.get('userId')).fetch();
    })
    .then(function (subscription) {
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(subscription));
    })
    .catch(LoginError, function (err) {
      return res.send('Login error');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      res.send('Other error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}
```

When the password doesn't match and it throws `LoginError`, the error is caught in the second catch block, not the catch block for `LoginError`. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Express.js, Bluebird, and Bookshelf/Knex where `User` is a Bookshelf model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bluebird distinguishes error constructors from predicate functions in a [`catch`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) by their inheritance:

> For a parameter to be considered a type of error that you want to
>   filter, you need the constructor to have its `.prototype` property be
>   `instanceof Error`.
>
> Such a constructor can be minimally created like so:
>
> ```
> function MyCustomError() {}
> MyCustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
> ```

You will need to do the same for your `LoginError`.

Or if you're using ES6, then `class LoginError extends Error {}`.

Comment: The ES6 version is not working for me. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927394/catch-error-type-in-bluebird-not-working

Comment: @TimScott: Probably you're transpiling ES6 to something where extending `Error` does not work.

Comment: Bergi: Yup that's it. Thanks.