# Catch Error Type in Bluebird Not Working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I have a custom error class:

```
class NetworkError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super('Network Error');
    this.name = 'NetworkError';
  }
}
```

And I want to handle it specifically:

```
import {NetworkError} from '../../common/errors';
someFunc().catch(NetworkError, err => {
  // this is missed
}).catch(err => {
  // this is hit
});
```

But it's skipping my custom catch and hitting the general catch. If I change it like so, it works:

```
someFunc().catch({name: 'NetworkError'}, err => {
  // this is hit
}).catch(err => {
  // this is missed
});
```

Obviously the first way is preferred. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your first variant will only catch the error if it is already a `NetworkError` type error object.  Does `someFunc()` throw that particular error?

Comment: The second variant probably works because you are passing in a generic object and the thrown error is a derivative of the generic object.  You need to show what error `someFunc()` is throwing before we can help more.

Comment: To test this out stop your debugger, and see what the object type of the error is! :)

Comment: Are you using Babel? If so, probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870684/why-doesnt-instanceof-work-on-instances-of-error-subclasses-under-babel-node/33877501#33877501

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Yup, that's it. And the suggested solution works. (If you want to submit as an answer, I will accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @loganfsmyth suggested in the question comments, it's a Babel limitation. This answer does the trick:

[Why doesn't instanceof work on instances of Error subclasses under babel-node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870684/why-doesnt-instanceof-work-on-instances-of-error-subclasses-under-babel-node/33877501#33877501)