# Bluebird's filtered catch broken when JS is generated by Typescript 2.0

Tags: typescript, bluebird

The error I see is identical to this (from here:[Catch Error Type in Bluebird Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927394/catch-error-type-in-bluebird-not-working)):

> ```
> I have a custom error class:
>
> class NetworkError extends Error {
>   constructor() {
>     super('Network Error');
>     this.name = 'NetworkError';
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> And I want to handle it specifically:
>
> ```
> import {NetworkError} from '../../common/errors';
> someFunc().catch(NetworkError, err => {
>   // this is missed
> }).catch(err => {
>   // this is hit
> });
> ```
>
> But it's skipping my custom catch and hitting the general catch. If I
>   change it like so, it works:
>
> ```
> someFunc().catch({name: 'NetworkError'}, err => {
>   // this is hit
> }).catch(err => {
>   // this is missed
> });
> ```
>
> Obviously the first way is preferred. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is the latest upgrade to Typescript 2.0. 
Specifically:

> As part of substituting the value of this with the value returned by a
>   super(...) call, subclassing Error, Array, and others may no longer
>   work as expected. This is due to the fact that constructor functions
>   for Error, Array, and the like use ECMAScript 6's new.target to adjust
>   the prototype chain; however, there is no way to ensure a value for
>   new.target when invoking a constructor in ECMAScript 5. Other
>   downlevel compilers generally have the same limitation by default.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work

This workaround fixed the problem for me, although **not for IE 10 and previous**:
Add the following code after any super call.

```js
if (Object.setPrototypeOf) {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(this, XHRError.prototype);
} else {
  this.__proto__ = XHRError.prototype;
}
```

Comment: if possible, using "target": "es2016", in the tsconfig will also work