# Custom error (for use with Bluebird) migrated from ES5 to ES6

Tags: javascript, error-handling, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I'm trying to convert this `ES5` syntax to `ES6 / ES7`. This is my `ES5` syntax:

```
function UserNotFound(message) {
  this.name = 'UserNotFound';
  this.message = message || 'Default Message';
  this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}

UserNotFound.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
UserNotFound.prototype.constructor = UserNotFound;
```

And here's how I'm catching the error:

```
.catch(UserNotFound, ()=> {
  console.log("User not found error caught");
})
```

This currently works. However, when converting the UserNotFound error syntax, it no longer catches the error. Here is what it looks like after I thought I had converted it correctly to `ES6 / ES7`:

```
export default {
  type: User,
  args: {
    email: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    }
  },
  resolve(_, args) {
    const { email } = args;

    return Db.User.find({ where: { email }})
      .then(result => {
        if (!result) {        
          throw new UserNotFound();
        }

        const user = result.dataValues;
        return sendResetEmail(user).then(()=> user);
      })
      .catch(UserNotFound, ()=> {
        const username = getEmailUsername(email);

        return Db.User.create({
          email,
          username
        })
        .then(({dataValues}) => {
          const user = dataValues;
          return sendResetEmail(user).then(()=> user);
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: In order for us to know what is wrong we would have to know how the `.catch()` method works. How does it check the "type" of the error?

Comment: Is that `catch` method of  bluebird?

Comment: @FelixKling I updated the post to show the context of the code

Comment: @Ram  I updated the post to show the context of the code

Comment: This should totally work in ES6. However, your transpiler might mess with the inheritance from the builtin `Error` class so that Bluebird doesn't recognise it any more. What environment are you using?

Comment: The `find` method probably returns a bluebird promise. Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056928/catching-custom-error-not-working-in-bluebird

Comment: Hey guys, I'm using ES6 built in promises, is that built off bluebird @Ram

Comment: Yeah, this looks like an error on our end (bluebird) - can you please file a report?

Comment: Also, your code above uses a bluebird feature (a useful one, predicate catch).

Comment: @Thomas If you were using native promises, then `.catch(UserNotFound, 
 () => {…})` would *not* work, neither with ES5 nor with ES6.

Comment: Are you using Babel? Possible duplicate: [Catch Error Type in Bluebird Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38927394/1048572)

Comment: Hey i got it to work using this: https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend

@Bergi do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: It was the babel transpiler, you were correct