# Custom Error extending class in Blubird catch not working

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I am using `ECMAScript 6`, `NodeJS 8.12` and `Bluebird 3.5.2`.

I have defined a custom error class:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor(message, someParameter) {
        super(message);
        this.name = 'CustomError';
        this.someParameter = someParameter;
    }
}
```

and my promises chain looks like this:

```
doSomething()
    .catch(CustomError, error => { ... })
    .then(result => { ... })
    .catch(error => { LOGGER.error(`something went terribly wrong: ${error}`); }
```

After rejecting in `doSomething()` with CustomError like this:
`new CustomError(error.message, parameterValue)`, the error message is:

```
something went terribly wrong: TypeError: Class constructor CustomError cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I pinpointed this to the `catch(CustomError, error =>` statement, which in order to not crash with `TypeError`, needs `catch(new CustomError, error =>`.

**Even after this, the `CustomError` catch isn't executed.**

My question is, why does this happen?
Is it a limitation of Bluebird?

Finally, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870684/why-doesnt-instanceof-work-on-instances-of-error-subclasses-under-babel-node/33877501#33877501) and it doesn't apply to my case, since I am not using Babel and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056928/catching-custom-error-not-working-in-bluebird?rq=1) which signifies that my approach should work (ES6 case in the answer).

Comment: The code you've shown should be fine on its own, so are you sure something in your app isn't loading Babel?

Comment: Isn't Babel something I should be using for transpiling? Through `npm list` I can see some babel packages which are required by `istanbul` which in turn are installed by `nyc`. But I am not currently using istanbul in my development workflow. For example, running my code entails `node ./examples/demo_server_client.js`.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Bluebird promise that you called `catch` on? Sounds more like the native `catch` method invoking its first callback…

Comment: You are exactly right! I was doing some refactoring and deleted the `const Promise = require('bluebird');`. I guess I could have avoided this if I used a namespace like solution, e.g. `bluebird.Promise`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Bergi Nice catch!

Comment: In the future, I'd really recommend including stack traces with errors, not just the messages, that would likely have made it clearer what was calling what.

Comment: @loganfsmyth You're right, will be doing that!